# When i increase size of box element the box below it goes down like 300px

Tags: css

```
/* Add a black background color to the top navigation */
body {
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: rgb(89, 90, 74);
}
.menu {
    background-color: rgb(54,54,53);
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 4;
}

.menu a {
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    color: rgb(176, 254, 118);
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-left: 15px;
}

.container {
    width: 90%;
    margin-left: 8%;
    margin-right: 8%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: 70px;
    padding: 30px 0px;
    position: absolute;
}
.container div {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 450px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: rgb(255,255,255);
    color: rgb(255,255,255);
    float: left;
    background-color: rgb(176, 254, 118);
    border-radius: 15px;
}


.ahover:hover{
    color: rgb(255,255,255);
    transition: 0.6s;
}
.ahover:not(:hover){
    color: rgb(176, 254, 118);
    transition: 0.6s;
}
#sellbox {
    color: rgb(54,54,53)

}
#sellbox ul {
    list-style: none
}
#sellbox #element {
    font-size: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
}
#sellbox #title {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    margin-top: 4px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
#sellbox:hover{
    padding: 3px;
    box-shadow: rgb(54,54,53) 3px;
}
#sellbox:not(:hover){
    padding: 0px;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

My problem is that the box that says "Buy me" when you hover it, it increases the size, but every other box moves, i tried to check already existing questions on this type but i havent found my answer, could you create a new fiddle with the working one and tell me what was the problem, thanks.
That's the css, also heres a fiddle `https://jsfiddle.net/t4r3L2v8/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
#sellbox:hover{
    padding: 3px;
    box-shadow: rgb(54,54,53) 3px;
}
#sellbox:not(:hover){
    padding: 0px;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

to

```
#sellbox{
    padding: 0;
}
#sellbox:hover{
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgb(54,54,53);
}
```

There's no need for `:not(:hover)` and as the other answer already said, the `padding: 3px` makes the element sightly so bigger that it takes up space in the next row.

Also there was something wrong with your box-shadow syntax. Read up on box-shadow on [CSS Tricks - Box Shadow](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/box-shadow/)

Answer (score 1):

**An element floated where it get space first & want to get most top &left space. when you increase padding it little bit take extra space from which break the next flow.**

> Replace your whole css by this-

```
   /* Add a black background color to the top navigation */
    body {
        margin: 0px;
        background-color: rgb(89, 90, 74);
    }
    .menu {
        background-color: rgb(54,54,53);
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 100%;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
        padding-top: 10px;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 4;
    }

    .menu a {
        font-size: 30px;
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        color: rgb(176, 254, 118);
        text-decoration: none;
        margin-left: 15px;
    }

    .container {
        width: 90%;
        margin-left: 8%;
        margin-right: 8%;
        overflow: hidden;
        margin-top: 70px;
        padding: 30px 0px;
        position: absolute;
    }
    .container div {
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        margin-left: 15px;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
        width: 250px;
        height: 450px;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: rgb(255,255,255);
        color: rgb(255,255,255);
        float: left;
        background-color: rgb(176, 254, 118);
        border-radius: 15px;
    }


    .ahover:hover{
        color: rgb(255,255,255);
        transition: 0.6s;
    }
    .ahover:not(:hover){
        color: rgb(176, 254, 118);
        transition: 0.6s;
    }
    #sellbox {
        color: rgb(54,54,53);
        transition: .5s;
    }
    #sellbox ul {
        list-style: none
    }
    #sellbox #element {
        font-size: 25px;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        margin-top: 0px;
        margin-bottom: 3px;
    }
    #sellbox #title {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 30px;
        margin-top: 4px;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
    #sellbox:hover{
        transform: scale(1.03);
        box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgb(54,54,53);
    }
    #sellbox:not(:hover){
        padding: 0px;
        box-shadow: none;
    }
```

Comment: thanks a lot, so when i want to change size without moving other items i use transform() ? also is there any way of how would i transform text size without moving other text's

Answer (score 1):

The main reason for this is that you're using padding to highlight your element, the total size of your box is calculated by summing content width, content height, padding and borders (content width + padding-left + padding-right + border-left + border-right) (content height + padding-top + padding-bottom + border-top + border-bottom) so when you increase the padding of a box, its size will increase, and as a result it may push neighbour boxes.

Check [box-model](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp) to understand more
[image]

### Solution:

One way to solve it is by defining your [box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) to border-box, this will prevent the total size of the box from increasing by decreasing the size of the content relatively to the border and padding.
it would be good if you add this property to every element in your page by adding the following css code:

```
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

## Your problem's solution:

One way to highlight your element is by using transform: scale(value), [scale()](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scale) will resize your element as shown in documentation (increase if value > 1, decrease if value < 1)
your code should look like this, feel free to change the value in order to understand how it works:

```
#sellbox:hover{
    transform: scale(1.03);
    box-shadow: rgb(54,54,53) 3px;
}
```

```css
/* Add a black background color to the top navigation */
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: rgb(89, 90, 74);
}
.menu {
    background-color: rgb(54,54,53);
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 4;
}

.menu a {
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    color: rgb(176, 254, 118);
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-left: 15px;
}

.container {
    width: 90%;
    margin-left: 8%;
    margin-right: 8%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: 70px;
    padding: 30px 0px;
    position: absolute;
}
.container div {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 450px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: rgb(255,255,255);
    color: rgb(255,255,255);
    float: left;
    background-color: rgb(176, 254, 118);
    border-radius: 15px;
}


.ahover:hover{
    color: rgb(255,255,255);
    transition: 0.6s;
}
.ahover:not(:hover){
    color: rgb(176, 254, 118);
    transition: 0.6s;
}
#sellbox {
    color: rgb(54,54,53)
    
}
#sellbox ul {
    list-style: none
}
#sellbox #element {
    font-size: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
}
#sellbox #title {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    margin-top: 4px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
#sellbox:hover{
    transform: scale(1.03);
    box-shadow: rgb(54,54,53) 3px;
}
#sellbox:not(:hover){
    padding: 0px;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="menu">
            <a class="ahover" href="#home">
                Home
            </a>
            <a class="ahover" href="#contact">
                Contact us
            </a>
            <a class="ahover" style="margin-left: 78%;" href="#signup">Sign up</a>
        </div> 
        <div class="container">

            <div id="sellbox">
                <p id="title">Buy me now</p>

                <p id="element">whew</p>
                <p id="element">whew</p>
                <p id="element">whew</p>
                <p id="element">whew</p>
                <p id="element">whew</p>
                <p id="element">whew</p>
                <p id="element">whew</p>

            </div>
            <div>
                
            </div>
            <div>
                
            </div>
            <div>
                
            </div>
            <div>
                
            </div>
            <div>
                
            </div>
            <div>
                
            </div>
            <div>
                
            </div>
            <div>
                
            </div>
            <div>
                
            </div>
            <div>
                
            </div>
            <div>
                
            </div>
            

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: this was the most useful comment here, thanks a LOOOT

Comment: Anytime, i'm glad it could help you.

Answer (score 0):

the boxes are moving because you are padding when you hover over it and it cause the element size to enlarge and to make space for that size it pushes items

Comment: and how would i fix it

Comment: either give all of the boxes `3 px padding` or give the 0 and remove padding from hover